# SMTP folder location

Tags: email, iis, incoming-email

I have a sucessful implementation of incoming email in my environment. I encountered an issue today however, after a change I made to the location of the SMTP "Badmail, Drop, Pickup and Queue" folders that service this feature.

We wanted to store these folders on a secondary drive instead of keeping it on the primary drive. I found a set of scripts that would handle this move:

```
cscript.exe c:\inetpub\adminscripts\adsutil.vbs set smtpsvc/1/pickupdirectory "M:\SMTP Mail Server\pickup"
cscript.exe c:\inetpub\adminscripts\adsutil.vbs set smtpsvc/1/queuedirectory "M:\SMTP Mail Server\queue"
cscript.exe c:\inetpub\adminscripts\adsutil.vbs set smtpsvc/1/dropdirectory "M:\SMTP Mail Server\drop"
cscript.exe c:\inetpub\adminscripts\adsutil.vbs set smtpsvc/1/badmaildirectory "M:\SMTP Mail Server\badmail"
```

So once I moved the directories the emails would arrive in the new location "drop" folder, however they would not be picked up by the sharepoint timer job that runs once a minute. I looked into the ULS log on the server and the job was executing properly.

I decided to test putting those emails into the old drop folder location "c:\inetpub\mailroot\" and they were delivered.

My question is...obviously something isn't syncing in my adjustment with SharePoint while IIS is taking the new setting something in SharePoint isn't. Is there a way to adjust this in SharePoint or nothing that can be done.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you have to re-enable the incoming mail service within the CentralAdmin.

At least on initial setup it asks you where you have your drop folder or if SharePoint should automatically detect the local SMTP service.

Comment: This worked, I disabled the incoming email feature through CA, then re-enabled it. Once this was done the folders worked correctly on my secondary drive.